# Does some form of function overloading exist in C?

Tags: c, function, overloading

Let's assume I want to create a function `first` that returns the first element of an array in C. Obviously I want to create something that accounts for all types.

I would start with this:

```
int first(int list[]) {
   return list[0];
}
```

Which works. Obviously...

I would now like to do the same for `char`

```
char first(char list[]) {
   return list[0];
}
```

Which does not compile as there is already a `first` function in the program.

How do you C guys handle this kind of scenarios?

Is one forced to go with different names?

```
int first_int(int list[]) {
   return list[0];
}

char first_char(char list[]) {
   return list[0];
}
```

Comment: You can't do that in C. It doesn't do this I'm afraid. You have to declare separate functions.

Comment: You might be able to get away with `_Generic` in C11, though I haven't tried it for an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C11 introduced [generic selections](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) to emulate overloading:

```
#define first(X)          \
    _Generic((X),         \
        int* : first_int, \
        char*: first_char \
    )(X)
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b6f3c6b506a8e0b)

Comment: Wow... that is impressive.